# C program crashes with use of a random variable

Tags: c, random

I want to populate a grid with 1s and 0s.
My program crashes due to the random variable r. It works perfectly fine with a constant(eg: say r=8). I have used `srand(time(NULL));`

```
void initGrid(int grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH])
{
    int i,j,r;
    for(i=0;i<GRID_HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        r = rand()%10;
        for(j=0;j<GRID_WIDTH;j++)
        {

            grid[i][j]= (i*j+i+j)%(r)<=2?1:0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What message is shown at the crash ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a "Divide by 0" error.

```
r = rand()%10;
```

gives the range of `r` as `0..9` so using that `0` for the modulus in `(i*j+i+j)%(r)` is causing the error.

I suggest you use

```
r = 1 + rand()%10;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fill it with 0 or 1, couldn't you just change it so that rand() gives the grid element it's value directly without needing to do the ternary modulus operation?

```
void initGrid(int grid[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<GRID_HEIGHT;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<GRID_WIDTH;j++)
        {

            grid[i][j]= rand()%2;
        }
    }
}
```

That would also get rid of the division by zero problem caused by `(i*j+i+j)%(r)` (as stated by Weather Vane in his answer)

Comment: Your solution will probably give similar number of 0 and 1 values. The mechanism in the question provides different distribution. The higher the value for r is, the more fields will become 0 in the inner loop.

Comment: That is absolutely true.